# How to merge two Expression<Func<T, T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression

I have two expressions like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, T> exp1 = x => new T { Id = 1 , Name = "string"}

Expression<Func<T, T> exp2 = x => new T { Age = 21 }
```

How can I merge them?

Result:

```
Expression<Func<T, T> exp3 = x => new T { Id = 1 , Name = "string" , Age = 21}
```

T is : `IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()`

IEntityBase:

```
public interface IEntityBase
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}

public virtual async Task UpdateAsync(string id, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory)
{
    Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory2 = s => new T { age = 21 };
    //Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactoryFinal = updateFactory + updateFactory2;
    await _context.Set<T>().Where(w => w.Id == id).UpdateAsync(updateFactoryFinal);
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. What is `T`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman T is : IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()

Comment: @m.h.bayan - No, that's what `T` is constrained to. It's not what `T` is.

Comment: This question is by far too broad. There are many things to do here, e.g. extract every expressions body, parse it, identify duplicates - how to handle those by the way - ... E.g. what if both expressions had `Age` specified?

Comment: @m.h.bayan - Can you please read [mcve] and then [ask]? If you have any questions about these then please ask. Then can you fix the question?

Comment: @m.h.bayan - Also, please understand you still haven't explained what `T` is. Can you provide a class def as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: @HimBromBeere updated question maybe help

Comment: You have to implement you own expression visitor. Check MS docs  (ExpressionVisitor Class) for details. Search web for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never use `Func` argument you can simplify your code and use `Func<T>`. Next method will merge two (or more) `MemberInitExpression` into one:

```
public static Expression<Func<T>> MergeExpressions<T>(params Expression<Func<T>>[] expressions)
  where T : new()
{
    var allBindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        var bindings = ((MemberInitExpression) expression.Body).Bindings;
        allBindings.AddRange(bindings);
    }

    var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), allBindings);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(body);
}
```

You can check it online [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrUzyY)

Comment: tank you - UpdateAsync method just get Func<T,T> entityframework-plus.net package

Comment: @m.h.bayan to make it work with `Func<T, T>` simply replace `Func<T>` and edit last line to `Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(body, Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)));`